# Can someone help me identify the font used in this game logo, for my personal project

Tags: fonts, logo, font-identification

Can someone help in with my personal project by identify the font used for "PORTABLE" in this logo. I've tried sites likefont.com but have have no luck. It would be very much appreciated.

[image: 喧嘩番長ポータル Logo]